# MediaQuery.of(context).padding is zero

Tags: flutter, padding, appbar

When I try to increase the top padding by giving `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top` doesn't work because all padding is zero.

I tried to wrap the parent widget with `MediaQuery.removePadding` but no luck. I don't have any `AppBar` upper in widget tree.

How can I solve this?

Comment: MediaQueryData parameters are `final` - you're only meant to read them. Padding is normally added with `Padding()`. A screenshot might be beneficial to your question. It's a little hard to parse what you're trying to do and how it relates to AppBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem in my case was that I was launching a modal sheet from a tile widget where the padding of that context was zero. So what I did was to give the tile widget a callback, and instead of launching the modal sheet with the context of the tile widget, I launched it with the context of the main screen and everything was fine.